# Fast insert in Link-like object

Tags: c#, object

In a real-time Agent-based modelling project I have the following problem: Assume I have some class MyClass with a public proporty X (X is a double). I need a class (call it FancyList) that can contain my objects in a sorted manner. If I insert a new MyClass-object it should be inserted between an object with a lower X and one with a higher X.

```
FancyList _fancyList = new FancyList();

// Allocate MyClass objects. The X proporty is defined in the constructor
MyClass c1 = new MyClass(2.0)
MyClass c2 = new MyClass(3.0)
MyClass c3 = new MyClass(2.5)

_fancyList.Insert(c1);
_fancyList.Insert(c2);
_fancyList.Insert(c3);

// In the fancyList c3 is after c1 and before c2. Therefore c1 is the first
// element, and c2 is the last element
```

It is important that the insert is as fast as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `SortedList<>` or a `SortedDictionary<>`.

They both implement `IDictionary`. According to [the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) the SortedDictionary has the faster Insert operation. Do read the rest of those specs.

```
FancyList _fancyList = new SortedDictionar<double, MyClass>();

// Allocate MyClass objects. The X proporty is defined in the constructor
...

_fancyList.Insert(c1.X, c1);
_fancyList.Insert(c2.X, c2);
_fancyList.Insert(c3.X, c3);
```